# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. Why?

Tags: python

```
students = [("Tom", "F"),
            ("Henry", "A"),
            ("Patrick","D")]

grade = lambda students:students[1]
sorted_students = students.sort(key=grade)

for i in sorted_students:
    print(i)
```

This program returns "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable", and I'd like to know why. I know that the value of sorted_students is None, but how did it get this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`students.sort()` does not return a sorted copy of the list, it just sorts *in place* `students`. Instead, you should use `sorted_students = sorted(students)`, or simply reuse `students` after having sorted it.